# Iterate on set and use \rowcolor

Tags: expl3, colortbl

I would like to generate the table contents with pure latex.

My draft is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_my_projects_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \addproject { m } {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_my_projects_seq { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \printprojects {} {
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
    Project & Content \\
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_my_projects_seq {
      \ifodd ##1
      \else
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
      \fi
      \textsf{##2} & ...\\
    }
  \end{tabular}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addproject{A}
\addproject{B}

\printprojects

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\rowcolor ->\noalign
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \global \let \CT@do@color \CT@@do@color...
```

In case I disable `\rowcolor...`, the PDF is generated. In case I put `\rowcolor...` before `\seq_map...`, the PDF is generated, too.

---

In case, I should switch from expl3 to lualatex, it is also OK for me. This is an exercise for me to learn something of [expl3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel).

Comment: \rowcolor wants to be at the begin of a cell, it won't  work if there is something not expandable before. Already a simple `\def\blub{}\rowcolor{lightgray}` will error.

Comment: I was sure that after `\\`, there is a beginning of a new cell. OK, the expl3 for loop is something "crashing" the state of being at the beginning of a new cell .

Comment: `\seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn` is non-expandable, as such uses `\protected`, and `\noalign` can't follow something that is `\protected` (`\protected` will stop the search for `\noalign` and similar and start the first cell). You can simply fix it by moving the `\\ ` after "Content" into the `\seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn` and removing the `\\ ` at the end of the mapping.

Comment: That being said, I don't think you need `\rowcolor` at all inside your loop, as you could simply use `\rowcolors` instead.

Comment: @Skillmon oh you posted a comment while I was writing an answer:-) But I have `\blub` to keep Ulrike happy.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ;-)))

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but no `\zz`, now nobody knows it's your code!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\seq_map_indexed_function:NN` which is expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_my_projects_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \addproject { m }
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_my_projects_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \printprojects {}
 {
  \rowcolors{2}{lightgray}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
    Project & Content \\
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_my_projects_seq { \textsf{##1} & ... \\ }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addproject{A}
\addproject{B}

\printprojects

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `xcolor` already provides for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_my_projects_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \addproject { m }
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_my_projects_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \printprojects {}
 {
  \rowcolors{2}{lightgray}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
    Project & Content \\
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l_my_projects_seq \__my_choosecolor:nn
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__my_choosecolor:nn
 {
  \textsf{#2} & ...\\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addproject{A}
\addproject{B}

\printprojects

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

TeX is in a very delicate state at the start of a cell, looking for spaning entries or (here) `\noalign`. Pretty much anything such as `\relax` or a `\protected` macro will stop the scan and start the cell content.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
11&22\\
\rowcolor{blue}
33&44  
\end{tabular}


\def\foo{\rowcolor{blue}}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
11&22\\
\foo
33&44  
\end{tabular}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \show\seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\protected\def\blub{\rowcolor{blue}}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
11&22\\
\blub
33&44  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note `\seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn` is `\protected` and `\foo` works but `\blub` does not.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is train some `expl3` coding:

The issue is described in David's answer and there is not much gain copying/reproducing it here. Instead this answer shows two ways to do what you want to do without triggering that error:

1. Use `\\` before `\rowcolor` in your mapping function (and remove it from the end of the first row), such that only fully expandable material precedes `\rowcolor` in each line (your `\int_if_odd:nF`):

   ```
   \NewDocumentCommand \printprojects {} {
     \begin{tabular}{lc}
       Project & Content
       \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_my_projects_seq {
         \\
         \int_if_odd:nF {##1} { \rowcolor{lightgray} }
         \textsf{##2} & ...
       }
     \end{tabular}
   }
   ```
2. Don't rely on `\rowcolor` inside your loop, but instead let `\rowcolors` do the job:

   ```
   \NewDocumentCommand \printprojectsB {} {
     \group_begin:
     \rowcolors{3}{lightgray}{}
     \begin{tabular}{lc}
       Project & Content \\
       \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_my_projects_seq { \textsf{##1} & ... \\ }
     \end{tabular}
     \group_end:
   }
   ```

Both result in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and its key `color-inside`) instead of `{tabular}`, you have directly the expected output. That's because `nicematrix`, with its built-in command `\rowcolor` does not use `colortbl` but PGF/TikZ. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_my_projects_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \addproject { m } {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_my_projects_seq { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \printprojects {} {
  \begin{NiceTabular}{lc}[color-inside]
    Project & Content \\
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_my_projects_seq {
      \ifodd ##1
      \else
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
      \fi
      \textsf{##2} & ...\\
    }
  \end{NiceTabular}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addproject{A}
\addproject{B}

\printprojects

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]